# How to uninstall yaml-cpp (build from source)

Tags: yaml, uninstallation, yaml-cpp

I tried to install yaml-cpp0.2.6 on my Oneric 11.10 server (on a pandaboard / armel architecture).

so i used:

```
$ hg clone http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/ (which appers to be yaml-cpp0.5.0)
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON ..
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

everything without a problem. But unfortunately I needed the 0.2.6 version of it. Therefore I would like to uninstall the 0.3.0 version with:

```
$ sudo make uninstall
```

But this gives me the failure

```
*** No rule to make target `uninstall'. Stop.'
```

Is there another way to uninstall it? Or to modify it, that my system don't need/want the yaml0.2.6 anymore?

Answer (score 0):

The installer just copies the header files to the directory `$PREFIX/include/yaml-cpp` and the library files to `$PREFIX/lib/libyaml-cpp.so`. (`$PREFIX` is probably `/usr/local`)

Just remove the header directory and the library files and it should be uninstalled.